# Take a set $S$ which has 6 vectors, and $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^5$. Why is $S$ linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that for a vector space $\mathbb{R}^5$, $\dim(\mathbb{R}^5)=5$ and thus a basis (b) (linearly independent and $span(b) = \mathbb{R}^5$) of $\mathbb{R}^5$ should have 5 vectors. I do not know how to link ideas together to understand why $S$ is linearly dependent? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5$ be a basis for $R^5$ and $u \in R^5$

If  $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5$ forms a basis than there exists real numbers $c_i$ such that

$u=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3+c_4v_4+c_5v_5$

$u=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3+c_4v_4+c_5v_5 \Rightarrow u-(c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3+c_4v_4+c_5v_5)=0$

As it can be seen, $v,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5$ are linearly dependent because coefficient of $v$ is not $0$

Comment: hello! do you mean u = c1v1 + c2v2 + c3v3 + c4v4 + c5v5 and for the last line do you mean "linearly dependent" instead of "linearly independent"? thank you!

Comment: I have fixed now. Thanks for warning :)

Comment: thank you! i understand it well now :")